# Android apps not working on Android 10. How to make them compatible?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I usually work in Android apps using Android Studio. But my apps are not working on devices which have Android 10 version. The target SDK and CompileSDK versions are 29. But the apps are not working and crashing.
[image]

Comment: Post the `LogCat` error

Comment: Tell exactly what is not working.

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch the exception your code caused.

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
This is what logcat is showing and linking to the Application java class.

Comment: You are using [a library for FFMPEG integration](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) that has not been updated in 5 years. [An issue was already filed for this problem](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/360). But, since the library is no longer being maintained, it is unlikely that the issue will be fixed.